# Counting index 1 value that occurs more than once in a list

Tags: list, python-3.x

I need help with counting in a list. I wondered how I can count number of how many times list index 0 has a different value than index 1.

Example `list = [("Hello","ab"), ("Hello", "cd"), ("Hi", "cd")]`. This is going to be counted as 1, since the key `"Hello"` index 0 has a value in index 1 that has occurred more than once(ab and cd). As you may have understood, my goal is to count all the index 0 that has different index 1 occurrence more than once. So if the index 0 "vop" has value occurrence more than 5 and the the index 1 "lop" has index 1 occurrence more than 2, this is going to be countes as 2 since both has index 1 that has occured more than once.

Edit: I can also use other data structures, to do the same thing.

Comment: Can you clarify your question with example inputs, outputs, and your current coding attempt?

Comment: It is really hard to explain, but I will try. My main goal here is to count how many apperences the key has in value. Example ("the","v"), ("the","x"), since "the" has occurd with 2 different values "v" and "x" this will mean that the word "the" has a value occurence more than 1 and this is going to be counted as 1. So i want to count all words that is like this. I dont know if I should use a dictionary or a list to do it. I have bunch of words which is in pairs, and I need to count all the words in index 0 that has more value occurences than 1. I hope you did understand me.